# No Cornmeal - steel cut oats to coat pan?

Tags: substitutions, non-stick, cornmeal

I'm trying to make English muffin bread, without the cornmeal (oops). Will steel cut oats work as the crumbly non-stick coating in the pans?

Comment: It would certainly give a very different result.